# How to sum the values of list to the power of their indices

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

How do I sum the values of list to the power of their indices in `Python 3`?

Example:

```
[3, 0, 2] = 3^1 + 0^2 + 2^3 = 11
```

The idea is to create a unique index for any possible combination of non-negative numbers in the list. This way, I can use the list to compute an index of *something*.

---

Edit: while the question has been answered, I just realized that the method does not create a unique index for any combination of non-negative integers in the list. To do so, assuming `a` is the number of possible integers, and based in the accepted answer,

```
sum(a ** i * j for i,j in enumerate(l, 0))
```

The idea is that each number will increase the index by an amount exponentially proportional to its position in the list. Assuming `a=4` (from `0` to `3`), the above example becomes

```
[3, 0, 2] = 4^0*3 + 4^1*0 + 4^2^2 = 35
```

Where the indices would range from `0` to `4^3-1=63`.

Comment: Hm, the edit might confuse more that it helps (regarding the original question and answer). Also, `enumerate(list, 0)` isn't needed :-) `enumerate(list)` by default starts indices from `0`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get the index and supply that to [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum):

```
sum(j ** i for i,j in enumerate(l, 1))
```

Specifying the `start` argument to `enumerate` as `1` assures indices will start from `1` (as you want) and not from `0` (the default which you get with a plain `enumerate`):

```
>>> l = [3, 0, 2]    
>>> sum(j ** i for i,j in enumerate(l, 1))
11
```

In a functional spirit, you could also utilize [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) with [`count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) from [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) passing in [`pow`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow) as the function to be mapped:

```
>>> from itertools import count
>>> sum(map(pow, l, count(1)))
11
```

These pretty much execute in approximately the same time; the generator expression to `sum` though offers a slight advantage of flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with numpy, which is often faster than iterating through lists:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: l = [0, 3, 4, 1]

In [3]: np.array(l) ** np.arange(len(l))
Out[3]: array([ 1,  3, 16,  1])

In [4]: np.array(l) ** np.arange(1, len(l) + 1)
Out[4]: array([ 0,  9, 64,  1])
```